# AWK: Concatenate field from different records

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, text-formatting

Given `file`:

```plaintext
2018-03-22 foo/bar/baz
2020-09-30 Lorem/ipsum/dolor
2021-10-01 yadda/yadda/yadda
2022-03-14 blah/blah/blah
```

(actual files contain thousands of such lines)

How to obtain the string **`2018-03-22_2022-03-14`**? This the concatenation of field 1 from record 1, followed by an underscore, then field 1 from the last record.

I've come up with this:

```plaintext
$ awk 'BEGIN{ORS="_"}NR==1{print $1} END{print $1}' file | sed 's/_$//'
2018-03-22_2022-03-14
```

It works, but it seems like there should be an *unconvoluted* way to get the same result using only `awk`, or perhaps only `sed`, without pipes or subshells. Is there in fact such a way?

Comment: What should the output be if there's only 1 line in the input file? What if the input file was empty?

Comment: @EdMorton In my case `file` is generated conditionally and will always have multiple lines. It is basically a timestamp and path list of all image files stored on a camera memory card. This list is created as an intermediate step in a script which saves a `tar` archive named `oldest_newest.tar` where "oldest" and "newest" refer to the timestamp range of the files in the archive (the paths part of the list is used later in the script to `mv` [and rename] the original files to directories based on timestamp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` to control the output:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{printf("%s_", $1)}END{print $1}' f
2018-03-22_2022-03-14
```

Comment: That's a good idea - using `printf` to print the field with a trailing `_` instead of `\n`

Comment: I've often used `printf` without a trailing `\n` to build up a line in parts, then finish off with either a  `\n` or a simple `print`.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because `printf` is less complicated than assigning a variable and will also work for any number of fields that need to be printed on the same line.

Comment: The value of `$1` in the `END` section is undefined behavior per POSIX. In some awks it'll be the value of the first field of the last line read, in other awks it'll be null, and in yet other awks it could be anything else.

Comment: Good point.  It works with GAWK, I tested it before replying.  I also tried for the minimum change consistent with solving the OP's problem.  If doing it myself I'd spread it over several lines and use more optional space.  Addressing your issue: change the END{} to `{last=$1}END{print last}` and it should work in any flavour of AWK.

Answer (score 2):

The `sed`-only version:

```
sed 's/ .*//;1h;$!d;H;g;y/\n/_/' file
```

- Use `s/ .*//` to remove everything after the whitespace, keeping the date only
- `1h` copies the date of line `1` in the `hold` space
- `$!d` `d`eletes all lines except for the last one
- if we get here, we are in the last line, so we append this line to the `H`old space with our first date, then copy both into the pattern space with `g`
- Now the only thing left to do is to replace the embedded newline (cause by appending) with the underscore: `y/\n/_/`

(And yes, it's a little bit shorter)

Comment: Thank you very much for a **`sed` only** solution and for explaining how this particular usage works.

Answer (score 2):

For portability, don't do `print $1` (or use `$anything`) in the `END` section as the value of `$0`, `$1`, etc. in the `END` section is undefined behavior per POSIX. In some awks `$1` in the `END` section will be the value of the first field of the last line read, in other awks it'll be null, and in yet other awks it could be anything else.

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk -v OFS='_' 'NR==1{beg=$1} {end=$1} END{print beg, end}' file
2018-03-22_2022-03-14
```

or to avoid printing a single `_` if the input file was empty:

```
awk -v OFS='_' 'NR==1{beg=$1} {end=$1} END{ if (NR) print beg, end}' file
```

The above assumes that if there's only 1 line in the input you want the same `$1` value duplicated with a `_` between them. If that's not what you want then update your question to clarify your requirements for that case.

Answer (score 1):

One way that is entirely `awk` (though not strictly POSIX-compliant as @EdMorton points out due to the field reference in the `END` section) is to set a variable to the value of field 1 from record 1, then at the end print this variable with `_` and field 1 from the last record:

```plaintext
$ awk 'FNR==1{d=$1} END{print d"_"$1}' file
2018-03-22_2022-03-14
```

*note: I hadn't planned on this being a "Q&A" type question, but SE was in read-only mode when I originally tried to submit the ***Q***, and in the intervening time I finally figured out an ***A***. I'd still like to see other answers, especially if they are shorter on the command line.*

Comment: The value of `$1` in the `END` section is undefined behavior per POSIX. In some awks it'll be the value of the first field of the last line read, in other awks it'll be null, and in yet other awks it could be anything else.

Comment: @EdMorton I was unaware of that. It seems so strange because POSIX does say `NR` and `FNR` are both defined for an `END` section.... I wonder what the reason was for doing this while leaving the fields themselves undefined?

Comment: I personally think leaving  $0, $1, etc. undefined was an oversight since `NF` is defined (to be the number of fields in the last record read) but it is what it is...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `head` and `tail` for large input file because `awk` and `sed` are slow for processing large file.

```bsh
$ cat input.txt
2018-03-22 foo/bar/baz
2020-09-30 Lorem/ipsum/dolor
2021-10-01 yadda/yadda/yadda
2022-03-14 blah/blah/blah
```

```bsh
{ head -n1 input.txt && tail -n1 input.txt; } |
  cut -d ' ' -f1 | paste -sd _ -
```

```
2018-03-22_2022-03-14
```

Comment: +1, but why you open a subshell? why not a codeblock `{ head -n1 input.txt && tail -n1 input.txt ; } ....` ?

Comment: Thank you, you are right, No need to open a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

This is longer than your command,
but it has the potential to be faster if the file is large:

```
echo "$(head -1 file | cut -d' ' -f1)_$(tail -1 file | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

If the file is actually tab-delimited, you can leave out the `-d' '`. 
If the file might begin with `-`,
or the `$1` values might contain backslashes,

```
printf '%s_%s\n' "$(head -1 file | cut -d' ' -f1)" "$(tail -1 file | cut -d' ' -f1)"
```

might be safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
fil=open('file','r')
fillist=fil.readlines()
filine=fillist[0].strip().split(' ')[0]
lasline=fillist[-1].strip().split(' ')[0]
print filine+"_"+lasline
```

output

```
2018-03-22_2022-03-14
```

Comment: Note that Python 2 is no longer supported; you should really start writing Python 3 code instead. You’re also reading all the file into memory, which isn’t necessary and will result in poor performance characteristics (both memory use and CPU time) with large files.